# Passport-Google-OAuth Callback Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have the following Node code using passport-google-oauth...

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', function(req,res) {
    console.log("callback");
    passport.authenticate('google', {
                successRedirect : '/signin',
                failureRedirect : '/signin'
    });
});
```

and...

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("ser");
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("des");
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

    clientID        : 'id',
    clientSecret    : 'key',
    callbackURL     : 'http://host/auth/google/callback',
},
function(token, rtoken, profile, done) {
   console.log("proc");
   console.log(profile);
   done(null, profile);
}));
```

The problem is,  the callback is getting called but nothing else happens. The processing function never hits.  The callback ends up timing out.  Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Is the line `console.log("callback");` executed?

Comment: Also what does you /signin route look like? Also should the callback be a get or post. I think it's usually a post.

Comment: maybe your problem is in GoogleStrategy. Try this: var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

Answer (score 1):

i just found out that passport-google-oauth package exports the following:

```
exports.Strategy =
exports.OAuthStrategy = OAuthStrategy;
exports.OAuth2Strategy = OAuth2Strategy;
```

which means, that the "default" (ie. Strategy) is not oauth2 at all... So you better use OAuth2Strategy explicitly. it worked for me. Took me hours to find out this was the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use "passport.authenticate('google')" middleware inside the second route '/auth/google/callback'.

your second route should be like :

```js
app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
     passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```