# Google Strategy Anonymous Function Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm trying to use passport so that users can log-on to my website using their google accounts. I'm using yarn with these relevant packages: passport@0.4.0, and passport-google-oauth20@^1.0.0. The general problem appears to be that the callback function specified in the `GoogleStrategy` isn't being run so the server is trying to load a page that doesn't exist, causing several errors.

What's currently happening is that I start the server with nodemon, passing the Google client ID and secret to process variables who's values are used by the `GoogleStrategy` (I have console logged them to make sure they are being correctly passed). I then visit the root page in the browser and click the log-in anchor which gets `/auth/google`. The google log-in screen that displays possible accounts to log-in with appears. I select my account and the server then gets a GET request to `/auth/google/callback?code=4/(a long string of characters)` which has a 500 error associated with it. After this, all the root page's files referenced in the pug file are GET requested, except that `auth/google` is added to the front of every request except the stylesheet.

An example output:

```
GET /auth/google 302 1.893 ms - 0
GET /auth/google/callback?code=4/(long string of text) 500 178.246 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 404 38.048 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 404 65.666 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css 404 89.565 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular/angular.js 404 115.541 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js 404 141.761 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.js 404 161.489 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js 404 23.809 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js 404 43.268 ms - 3087
GET /auth/google/apps/angular_app.js 404 62.520 ms - 3087
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 86.279 ms - -
```

The page at this point appears to only have what's in its main pug file and the css file; none of the ng-repeats or ng-includes work for example. The URL in the browser at this point is `http://(my domain)/auth/google/callback?code=4/(a long string of characters)`

Here's the relevant code in the express file for the root page:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

console.log('google client id: ' + process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
console.log('google client secret: ' + process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
router.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://(my domain)/auth/google/callback'
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log('start of callback');
  return done(null, profile);
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile']} ));
router.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: '/',
  function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}));

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  console.log('logged out');
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `console.log('start of callback');` isn't being executed during any point of the sequence in the second paragraph. The `console.log('logged out');` is being executed when the log-out anchor is clicked and the redirect function called afterwords is executed as well.

Here are most of sources I've been looking at for possible reasons the strategy hasn't been running the anonymous callback function:

- [Passport-Google-OAuth Callback Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219121/passport-google-oauth-callback-not-working)
- [Custom Callback never called when Google Auth on passportjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366909/custom-callback-never-called-when-google-auth-on-passportjs)
- [Passport Callback isn't called Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224218/passport-callback-isnt-called-google-api)
- [how to redirect to original page after successful authentication using passport-google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586774/how-to-redirect-to-original-page-after-successful-authentication-using-passport)
- [Passport-Google-OAuth Callback Not working when used in Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729592/passport-google-oauth-callback-not-working-when-used-in-web-service)
- [Google-oauth2 passport not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042120/google-oauth2-passport-not-working)
- [Passport Authenticate doesn't redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834707/passport-authenticate-doesnt-redirect)
- https://www.jokecamp.com/tutorial-passportjs-authentication-in-nodejs/
- https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2
- http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#redirects
- http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually tried adding session functionality to see if the combination of Passport and Google oauth 2.0 required it. That was the case, after adding basic session functionality, the callback function was called and the process completed. I didn't find documentation stating that sessions were required but after rereading the "read me" page in the GitHub repository, which is linked in my question above,

> Also both sign-in button + callbackURL has to be share the same url, otherwise two cookies will be created and it will lead to lost your session

it is implied that sessions are required by Google oauth 2.0.